# Расшифровка результата функции GetLocaleInfoEx()

Tags: winapi, локаль

Суть задачи в определении характеристик пользовательской локали (такие как страна, язык, формат даты и времени и т.п.). Вроде как, я нашёл направление, в котором нужно идти: получаю имя локали с помощью GetUserDefaultLocaleName(), затем передаю его в GetLocaleInfoEx() вместе с константой (вроде LOCALE_ICOUNTRY, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE и др.), определяющей возвращаемую характеристику. Последняя функция в качестве возврата предоставляет строку, содержащую шестнадцатиричное число, а что с ним делать, не имею ни малейшего понятия. Единственный доступный источник - это документация от Microsoft, но и там, честное слово, найти ничего не могу. Попадаются лишь темы с близкими к моей проблеме названиями, но описывающие немного другое.

Comment: Загляните, это Вам подойдет? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно получить языковой идентификатор:

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t localeName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    int ret = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(localeName, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        LCID lcid = 0;
        if (GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName, LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER | LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, (LPWSTR)&lcid, sizeof(lcid)))
        {
            cout << hex << lcid;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Дальше по ссылке, которую скинул Юрий можно посмотреть чему соовтетсвует это значение. В моем случае результат 0x0409, что соответсвует SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
Если нужно получить название страны, например, то можно использовать `LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDCOUNTRYNAME` параметр:

```
#define COUNTRY_NAME_MAX_LEN 80

int main()
{
    wchar_t localeName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    int ret = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(localeName, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        wchar_t wxCountry[COUNTRY_NAME_MAX_LEN];
        if (GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName, LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDCOUNTRYNAME, wxCountry, COUNTRY_NAME_MAX_LEN))
        {
            wcout << wxCountry;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В моем случае этот код выводит Unites States. Что бы получить название языка и диалект, например, English (Unites States), используйте параметр `LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME`

Comment: А что делать, если нужно программно сопоставить результату строку из таблицы? Switch-case - первое, что приходит в голову, но это далеко не лучшее решение.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, обычно делают что-то типа std::map<LCID, строковое описание>. Вместо строкового описания может быть какая-нибудь другая пользовательская структура со строковым описанием и, возможно, другой нужной инфой. А дальше, после получения LCID, просто из map берут нужное значение.

Comment: Я только сейчас понял, что между нами, возможно, возникло недопонимание. Начну по порядку. Я обнаружил, что есть несколько групп однотипных констант, в числе которых есть LOCALE_I* и LOCALE_S*. Первая группа, как я понял, возвращает числовые значения, а вторая - строковые. И если взять, к примеру, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE и LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, то в документации написано, что первая константа вернёт идентификатор языка, а вторая - его название. Но если вывести строку, которую вернула эта вторая константа, то получится что-то вроде этого: "0000000443BCF590". ...

Comment: ... Именно об этом шестнадцатиричном числе я говорил, описывая проблему. Подобный результат возвращает и GetUserDefaultLocaleName(), и, что самое странное, с каждым запуском правая часть строки меняется. Вы случайно не знаете, что это за содержимое, и чем различаются константы типа LOCALE_I* и LOCALE_S*, а то я совсем запутался.

Comment: Вы хотите получить страну или язык? Согласно документации `LOCALE_SLANGUAGE` - устаревшая константа и вместо неё нужно использовать что-то, что перечислено тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-slocalized-constants

Comment: Добавил в ответ код, для использования LOCALE_S параметров. То, то что получается у вас с S-параметрами - это просто числовое представление строки. Сконрветируйте его в unicode-строку и будет вам счастье

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96310/discussion-between-rudolfninja-and-ghostinecatnewyear).